# How do I add items after a list in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

A list component in Sencha Touch 2 supports both items in the configuration (buttons, fields, etc.) and it's itemTPL which is filled by the store that gets bound to it.  When you build this, everything works like you'd expect -- except that the items configuration items you add always show up before the list.  I can't come up with a way to make them appear at the bottom of the list (I want to make a "Reply" button that shows up at the bottom of a list of forum type posts).  I can set docked : 'bottom' which will get it to the bottom of the parent container, but that is just a fixed position and not really displaying *after* the list items.

Anyone know what to do here?

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by setting your parent container layout, I mean the container in which your list is laid, to `vbox`. Then:

```
xtype: 'container'
layout: 'vbox'
items: [your_list, your_button_below_list, ...]
```

will show your list first, then below it is your button, and so on.

Hope it helps.

P/S: To be exact, if you want to scroll to the bottom of the list then the button is there, you have to set this config to your list: `scrollable:false` or give it a `minHeight`

Comment: Thank you for this!  This is the kind of information that the docs don't do a very good job of conveying.